# Wrong layer dimension Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I am building a model for road-segmentation using the KITTI dataset. When i was trying to train my model, i got a following error

```
Error when checking target: expected activation_26 to have 2 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (289, 160, 576, 2)
```

My x has a shape of (289, 160, 576, 3) and y (289, 160, 576, 2). My model looks like this

My model.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(96, (5, 5), padding="same",input_shape=(160, 576, 3)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),  dim_ordering="tf"))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2),  dim_ordering="tf"))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))


    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2) ,  dim_ordering="tf"))



    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    # softmax classifier
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))


   #Here is my data augmentation 
    aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40, width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2, shear_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.2,
     fill_mode="nearest")
    adam = Adam(lr=1e-5)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(x, y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
         validation_data=(x, y), steps_per_epoch=len(x) // BATCH_SIZE,
         epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
```

I guess that it is an issue with a last layer. My y is multi dimensional but my last layer is 2 dimensional. When i change my layer to `model.add(Dense((289, 160, 576, 2)))` , i get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Comment: Why do you use `Flatten()` if your y data are in a multi-dimensional format? Seems to me that after your final `MaxPooling` layer, what you need are further `Conv2D` and `UpSampling2D` layers, similar to what you would do with an autoencoder

Comment: Is my last layer supposed to be conv2d(after UpSampling2D)? Can you give me a link to an example?

Comment: Your last layer should be `Conv2d(2, (a, b), ...)`, where `2` is the number of channels you have in y, i.e. `(None, 160, 576, **2**)` and `a` and `b` are filter sizes such that whatever size the second to last layer is, it is mapped to a height and width of `160` and `576`. (Note that the first dimension, `289` is the number of observations; it is replaced with a placeholder `None` and its actual size will vary based on the batch size you choose)

Comment: Thanks, but how could i implement a UpSampling2D layer?

Comment: I tried model.add(Convolution2D(5,( 160, 576), activation='relu')).  I got a result ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 160 from 147 for 'conv2d_254/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,512,147,5], [160,576,512,5]. Why is there supposed to be 5 and not 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, ZeroPadding2D, Convolution2D
from keras.models import Sequential 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(96, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=(160, 576, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf"))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf"))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering="tf"))

# at this point the representation is (20, 72, 512)
# we need to evolve this to become (160, 576, 2)

#### This part I would leave out:

# model.add(Flatten())
# model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# # softmax classifier
# model.add(Dense(2))
# model.add(Activation("softmax"))

#### ... and replace it with:

model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding="same")) # (20, 72, 128)
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2))) # (40, 144, 128)
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same")) # (40, 144, 64)
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2))) # (80, 288, 64)
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), padding="same")) # (80, 288, 16)
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2))) # # (160, 576, 16)
model.add(Conv2D(2, (2, 2), activation="softmax", padding="same")) # (160, 576, 2)


print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now i got it.ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_275 to have shape (2, 576, 24) but got array with shape (160, 576, 2). Why is my shape reversed?

Comment: @KyrKalash have you tried switching data_format='channels_last'?

Comment: Your input data appears to be in "channels_first" format. Try adding the `data_format="channels_first"` argument to the convolution layers. See the Keras documentation on `Conv2D` here: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/. Look for the `data_format` input parameter. By the way, I forgot to mention the way you've set up your model results in a *huge* number of parameters that need to be fit (over 6 million) for such a small model. This is mainly because you are stretching the number of channels from `3` all the way to `512`. I don't know if that was your intention

Comment: I changed model a little bit . I got the following error ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_127 to have shape (156, 572, 2) but got array with shape (160, 576, 2). How can I upscale my layer?